# twisted cubic is irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I was reading Professor Vakil's FOAG, in exercise 9.3A needs to study the twisted cubic which is defined to be the vanishing locus of three homogenuous equation $wz = xy , x^2 = wy , y^2 = xz$ in $\Bbb{P}^3_k$

I want to show that it's irreducible and isomorphic to $\Bbb{P}^1_k$

---

My attempt: It's not hard to show that $C$ isomorphic to $\Bbb{P^1}$,

for there is a morphism from $$\varphi: \Bbb{P}^1_k \to C\subset \Bbb{P}^3_k\\ [s:t]\mapsto [s^3:s^2t:st^2:t^3]$$

if we assume the coordinate on $\Bbb{P}^3_k$ to be $[w:x:y:z]$ then we see the twisted cubic is covered by $\{w\ne 0\}$ and $\{z\ne 0\}$ on $w \ne 0$ we have $$\{w\ne 0\} \cap C \to \Bbb{P}^1_k\\ [w:x:y:z]\mapsto [w:x]$$
and on $z\ne 0$ we have $$\{z\ne 0\}\cap C\to \Bbb{P}^1_k \\ [w:x:y:z]\mapsto [y:z]$$

since $wz = xy$ they glue together,since coinside on the overlap, and inverse to $\varphi$. therefore we prove $C \cong \Bbb{P}^1_k$.

As a direct consequence twisted cubic is irreducible since $\Bbb{P}^1_k$ is irreducible.

---

It's possible to read it directly from the graded ring corresponding to twisted cubic say $$k[w,x,y,z]/(wz-xy,x^2-wy,y^2 -xz)$$

Recall in the affine case the closed subscheme is irreducible iff the defining ideal is prime, is there a similar criterion for projective scheme?

Comment: This comes down to the following question: is it possible for a projective scheme to be reducible and yet have its restriction to every affine chart be irreducible?

Comment: The closure of an irreducible set is irreducible.

Comment: thank you @Tabes Bridges  .I am not sure but there seems not to have a reason that union of irreducible set still being irreducible?

Comment: Oh thank you @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez maybe I got what you mean, do you mean if I remove a point it will be a affine scheme, which can be checked to be irreducible then the closure will be the twisted cubic which is still irreducible?

Comment: Indeed! ${}{}{}$

Comment: If you have figured out a solution from the comments you should post it as an answer

Comment: Ok ronno, I will have a try later

Comment: @TabesBridges if the restriction to every affine chart is irreducible AND all charts mutually intersect then a scheme is irreducible. Isn't the second part of the last sentence necessary?

Comment: @user128787 I'm thinking of closed subschemes of projective space with the restriction of the standard affine cover, which typically (but maybe not always?) satisfy this hypothesis.

Comment: @TabesBridges oh yes sure (at least for the twisted cubic), I just wanted to make sure